# Round to nearest ten using printf

Tags: c, printf, c99

The precision specifier for floating point values given to `printf` allows a programmer to specify the number of digits to be printed **after** the decimal place. Does `printf` have a similar precision specifier which allows the programmer to specify how many digits **before** the decimal point to round the value?

For example, if I pass `157` to `printf`, I want the value `160` to be printed to the screen if I tell it to round to the *nearest ten*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So far as I know, there's no way to get `printf` to do that.  You'd have to round the value manually before passing it to `printf`.  For example:

```
printf("%d\n", myRound(157, 10));

int myRound(int x, int b) {
    return ((x + b/2) / b) * b;  // TODO: handling for overflow, etc.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`printf` doesn't alter the data, the format specifiers only specify how it's displayed. If you give `printf` `157` it will print `157` in some form or another.

Check out the rounding functions in the C [math library](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/) for rounding functions.

Answer (score 1):

No. The closest you can probably get with `printf` is by using scientific notation:

```
printf("%.1e\n", 157.0);
```

This will print `1.6e+02`, which is definitely not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I like the `myRound(157, 10)` solution, but thought I would add:

```
printf("%d0\n", (n+5)/10);   // int n;
printf("%.0f0\n", x/10);     // double x; (fails for INF, NAN)
```